# How to access localhost from a NOX app player android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, localhost, wampserver

I need to get access to my wamp server localhost from `NOX app player`.

Which link I could use to get it. the 10.0.2.2 not working with it...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the IP to be 172.17.100.2. Found this out by installing the Android "Fing" app to browse the network and tried the first result. Works great. Not sure why NOX didn't stick with the usual 10.0.2.2 like most other emulators I've used.

Comment: What if I use a port? like 172.17.100.2:8080? Nox not able to reach such address...

Answer (score 2):

With NOX 3.7.0 I can connect to host machine using 192.168.56.1.

It listed in ipconfig /all (I use windows 10)

Answer (score 2):

Use your machines ip address if you are connected to a network e.g 10.70.10.3 instead of using 127.0.0.1/localhost

> credit: sechanakira's comment

This has worked for me. My machine is connected to a LAN.

### Steps:

1. Run ipconfig to get my IP.
2. Replace 127.0.0.1 with my IP in NOX app player

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Could you elaborate on this answer, indicating if you have tested this yourself, the outcome, and why this might work over other answers proposed.

Comment: Yes, this has worked for me. My machine is connected to a LAN. I took the following steps: 1. Run ipconfig to get my IP. 2. Replace 127.0.0.1 with my IP in NOX app player

Answer (score 1):

NOX 3.7.6.3.I use PC's ip and port number (for example 192.168.0.200:80).
ip from ipconfig, port - whatever you set for your localhost(80 by default).
And it works with **Nox app player** 6.2.5.3.

Answer (score -1):

This is working for Genymotion. Try to change your IP to http://10.0.3.2/ instead  10.0.2.2. Reply whether this works or not.